# Sahi unable to open pdf file on clicking print button

Tags: sahi

[image]

Sahi unable to display pdf file .Can anyone please provide some tips.Verified testsuite.properties everything seems to be okay.

Comment: Provide the error at least please

Comment: <a href='/_s_/dyn/Log_getBrowserScript?href=/sakuli/TESTSUITES/test_1/testcases/KV/sakuli.js&n=1262'><b>Click for browser script</b></a>